# I made a Discord.js bot, but when i tell it to DM someone, it types that person's ID in the DM

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

so i made this Discord.js bot, and i programmed it to DM a user by his userID or mention... When i tell it to DM someone [$send  ] it works, but in the message it sends that users ID.

[image: Screenshot:]

Code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on ("ready", () => {
    console.log("the bot is ready...");

    client.user.setGame ("prefix is $");
});

const prefix = "$";
client.on ("message", (message) => {

    msg = message.content.toLowerCase();

    if (message.author.bot) return;

    mention = message.mentions.users.first();

    if (msg.startsWith (prefix + "send")) {
        if (mention == null) { return; }
        message.delete();
        mentionMessage = message.content.slice(8);
        mention.sendMessage(mentionMessage);
        message.channel.send("sent");
    }

});

client.login('tokenHereLmao');
```

Comment: message.content is a String, slice / transform it so that it cuts out the mention. Your Discord ( Bot )  receives a Mention in the Format of `<@userid>` and then the Client transforms it to `@Name` obviously your Bot does not do this.

Comment: How do i fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to do this would be to replace:

```js
msg = message.content.toLowerCase();

if (message.author.bot) return;

mention = message.mentions.users.first();

if (msg.startsWith (prefix + 'send')) {
    if (mention == null) return;
    message.delete();
    mentionMessage = message.content.slice(8);
    mention.sendMessage(mentionMessage);
    message.channel.send('sent');
}
```

to a proper command handling structure like:

```js
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/); 
// transforms message like "$sEnd <@486615250376851477> Hello!" into an Array
// like ['sEnd', '<@486615250376851477>' 'Hello!']
const cmdname = args.shift().toLowerCase();
// takes the first element of the array and makes it toLowerCase
// cmdname = send
// args = ['<@486615250376851477>' 'Hello!']

mention = message.mentions.users.first();


if (cmdname == 'send')) {  // Checks for the Commmand
        if (mention == null) return message.channel.send('You need to mention someone');
        message.delete();
        args.shift(); // args = ['Hello!']
        mention.send(args.join(' '));  
        // args.join(' '); would transform ['Hey', 'how', 'are', 'you?'] to 
        // "Hey how are you?" and then send it
        message.channel.send("sent");
}
```

If you need a good resource to setup a good bot with a nice Structure use the offical and open-source guide maintained by the community and creators of discord.js at: http://discordjs.guide

Comment: Now the bot can only mention the people that are in the server :p
it was used to mention people in mutual servers, even if i do the command from my server.

Comment: Any script to add?